# How to reset SqLite database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want my users to be able to reset the application, then I need to reset the SQLite database that I have created. 
How can I do that? I want to reset the database or delete and recreate the database.

Comment: don't delete entire instead clear all tables data from database.

Answer (score 18):

Just delete your database by

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Please make sure to close your database before deleting.

Comment: I tryed delet database. The problem is that when I do this, I cant insert anything again.

Comment: After delete, call the create database script at`onCreate` of the opening activity

Comment: Make sure to close your database before deleting.

Answer (score 9):

Bit late but this can help other people

```
public void clearDatabase(String TABLE_NAME) {  
   String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME;  
   db.execSQL(clearDBQuery);  
   }
```

This should remove all the rows from the table refer documentation of SQLite database [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)!

Comment: Your the champ! Man.

Answer (score 3):

Working for me.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just drop tables from database

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+TABLENAME);
```

and again create the table in same database.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the content of all your tables using `delete from table where 1=1`, or you can call your database `onCreate` method again

Comment: Calling onCreate worked for me. I passed getWritableDatabase() from my SqlLiteOpenHelper sublass as the onCreate parameter btw.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option to clear the table from the database

**Firstly**

If you wan to delete the data on specific row you need to add this code in the database class

```
    public Boolean specification(int id, String table_name)
     {
         return db.delete(table_name, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
     }
```

and add the below code when you want to perform this action

```
  db.deleteSpecificOrder(id, "table_orders");
```

**Secondly**

If you want to delete all the data from th table then you just need to add below code into your database

```
public void clearDatabase(String TABLE_NAME) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(clearDBQuery);
}
```

and then add the below line where you want to perform that action

```
 db.clearDatabase("table_food_items");
```

I Hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
 try {

        presenter = new NonioApplicationPresenterImpl(this);

        masterHelper = presenter.getDevOpenHelper();
        sqLiteDatabase = presenter.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = presenter.getDaoMaster();
        daoSession = presenter.getNewSession();

    } catch (SQLiteException sqLiteException) {
        deleteDatabase(NonioApplicationPresenter.DATABASE_NAME);
    }
```